# Mongoose Validation Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I am trying to create records in mongodb through mongoose and express, but I am getting validation errors:

```
ValidationError: User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., 
email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required.
at ValidationError.inspect (D:\Projects\addlife\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:56:24)
at formatValue (util.js:430:38)
at inspect (util.js:324:10)
at format (util.js:191:12)
at Console.log (console.js:130:21)
at D:\Projects\addlife\app.js:104:21
```

Here is the mongoose schema:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
//User Schema

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
password:{
    type: String,
    required: true
}
});

let User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Here is the submit post route:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
let user = new User();
user.name = req.body.name;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.password = req.body.password;

user.save(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }else{
        res.redirect('/');
        console.log('redirected');
    }
    });
});
```

Can't seem to debug the mongoose validation error.

Comment: The `req.body.name` is most definitely `undefined`.

Comment: Can you log your `req.body.name`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing the name and password parameters in your request? This may be due to the result of you not providing these variables in your post request.